# C++ Builder 2009 File In Project Manager File Icon Has 2 Checks

Tags: cvs, c++builder

I'm using CVS with C++ Builder 2009.

One of my files has 2 check marks on the small icon in the Project Manager Panel. My other files do not have these check marks.

The file is checked in and I have the latest source from the code repository. Can someone please let me know what these check marks mean.

[image: Image of 2 check marks]

Answer (score 1):

This indicates that you have set local options for this compilation unit. Right click on the file in the project manager and choose `Edit Local Options`. You should then be able to see which options differ for this file from the project's defaults.

Comment: After `Edit Local Options` is there a particular section I should be looking in?